# How to update iframe source query string without reloading

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe, query-string

Is there a way to update an iframe source query string without reloading the frame content?

I am looking to change the source `"example.com/?power=0&level=0"` to `example.com/?power=99&level=24`

```
<iframe 
  id="myFrame"
  src="example.com/?power=0&level=0" />
```

If there is no way to do the following without reloading the iframe, are there any other options out there to explore?

Comment: And what would be the point of changing the URL if it doesn't update the content ?

Comment: The query parameters will cause some methods to fire up on the iframe source server. For example, if you have a log viewer where you specify the `lineNumber`, it will animate the view to scroll down to the line number in question. But by having the iframe reloading, the whole animation scroll is no longer observed.

Comment: Why would someone create a page where animations happen based on the querystring changing, when the querystring changing causes a reload of the page?

Comment: I agree, it is something uncommon to do. Just thought there might be a way to do it.

Comment: The only option would be the History API, but I don't think that works on an iFrame, other than maybe if called from within the iframe

Comment: Just to explain why would someone be interested in this request... Some Single Page Apps are leveraging History for client side in app page navigation (routing). They also leverage query string client side. They usually do it by using History pushState.